# MongoClient's connection isn't being closed when using mongodb driver on nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

#### Description

When I call `client.close()` on an opened `MongoClient` connection and check the connection status using `client.isConnected()`, the connection status still reads true (`client.isConnected()` returns true)

#### Steps to reproduce

MongoConfiguration.ts file

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

export default class MongoConfiguration {
  private _client: MongoClient;
  get client(): MongoClient {
    return this._client;
  }

  constructor() {
    const uri = `mongodb://${hostname}:${port}`;
    this._client = new MongoClient(uri);
  }

  public connectClient= async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Connecting to mongoDB');
      await this._client.connect();
    } catch (err) {
      await this.disconnectClient();
      throw err;
    }
  };

  public disconnectClient= async () => {
    try {
      await this._client.close();
      console.log('Connection to MongoDB closed');
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  };
```

Test file

```
import { describe } from 'mocha';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import MongoConfiguration from './MongoConfiguration';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

describe('Test mongo client connection', () => {
  let mongoConfiguration: MongoConfiguration;
  let client: MongoClient;

  before(() => {
    mongoConfiguration = new MongoConfiguration();
    client = mongoConfiguration.client;
  });

  it('should connect and close connection successfully', async () => {
    await mongoConfiguration.connectClient();
    expect(client.isConnected()).equals(true);
    await mongoConfiguration.disconnectClient();
    expect(client.isConnected()).equals(false);
  });
});
```

#### Expected result

The test passes successfully

#### Actual result

The test fails because the last `client.isConnected()` remains `true`

#### Packages used

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.3",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.7",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.43"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.1",
    "@types/mongodb": "^3.3.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  }
```

As far as I know, this should be straight forward but I guess I'm doing something (or a lot of things) wrong. So please what is the right way to close a mongodb connection?

### Edit

I tried adding a timeout in the test to wait for some seconds to see if the connection does get closed but `client.isConnected()` remains `true`

New test

```
it('should connect and close connection successfully', async () => {
    await mongoConfiguration.connectMongoClient();
    expect(client.isConnected()).equals(true);
    await mongoConfiguration.closeMongoClient();
    setTimeout(() => console.log(client.isConnected()), 5000); // Logs true
  });
```

I'm beginning to doubt the connection ever gets closed and the github link doesn't support opening issues

Comment: Hi, can you use a `setTimeout` in your `await this._client.close();` like; I know you're using `await` and it should be enough, but the native mongo client usually takes at least 1ms before it closes the connection. It'd be good if you try that just to see if you get the expected behavior.

Comment: Tried that and unfortunately still didn't get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb drive official [doc](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/MongoClient.html#close) said that `close`  function is like a callback style function, it just return a dummy Promise if no callback passed. Source code [lib/mongo_client.js, line 310](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/lib_mongo_client.js.html) . This mean the `await` keyword does not help wait until the connection is disconnected.

```
await mongoConfiguration.disconnectClient();
expect(client.isConnected()).equals(false);
```

`client.isConnected()` executes immediately after `await mongoConfiguration.disconnectClient();` line, while `await this._client.close();` still did not "finish", then `client.isConnected()` will be `true`.

Solution, convert `this._client.close()` into a promise.

```
  public disconnectClient = async () => {
    try {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // wait until it finish the `close` job
        this._client.close((error) => {
          if (error) {
            return reject(error);
          }
          resolve();
        });
      });
      console.log('Connection to MongoDB closed');
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error still persists. `client.isConnected()` is still true